# Observable chaining, flatMap and type casting

Tags: typescript, promise, observable

I'm new to observables and I want to learn.

I have an API.get() method that returns a promise of type T as T is:

```
export interface T {
    data?: object;
    errors?: [object];
    extensions?: {
        [key: string]: any;
    };
```

What I would like to do is to call this API in a function like this:

```
public get(): Observable<R>{

   // Convert API.get():Promise<T> to an observable
   // get T.data and cast it to type R
   // return observable<R>
   // catch potential error in T.errors 

}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is `R` a defined type, or do you want to make the `get` function generic?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use rxjs6, you can convert from Promise to Observable by using the `from` function. Then you pipe to the `map` operator to cast it. I'm not sure if R is a defined interface or if you want `get` to be generic. If the latter is true, you need to put `<R>` after `get` too, and then use the `as` keyword. This will probably fail for most types though.

```
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

/*...*/
public get<R>(): Observable<R>{
    const obs = from(API.get());
    return obs.pipe(map(response => response as R));
}
```

Comment: and you can  also play with `catchErrors` to fulfill the part about errors in the question

Comment: Thanks. R is an interface like

Comment: Ok, if R is a known interface, we would need to know what it looks like to cast it properly. But if for instance `R` has only a `data` field, the conversion would look like this: `<R>{data: response.data}`

Comment: @PAc0 In my case, I have two sources of error:
1. when API.Get() fails
2. T.errors is not empty. 

 get<R>() is in my service layer and I subscribe to it at component level. how can I check for all those errors when I subscribe to it?

Comment: I'd suggest you do it before you subscribe, using the `catchError` operator. Place it after the `map` inside the pipe. You should be able to find good documentation by googling. If you still can't figure it out, create a new question on stackoverflow where you mention what you've tried.